# Career path for a CS undergrad who wants to enter into mathematics research

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am a second year compsci undergraduate. My program is a 4 year program, so I have 2 more years left. However, I feel that I am not motivated enough, or not satisfied with the quality of teaching in my courses, and to top it off I am slowly falling "in love" or at least beginning to profoundly like mathematics. I want to  have the opportunity of becoming a mathematician (possibly retaining my knowledge in CS, too) by entering a good MSc program in mathematics in a competitive university.

In relation to my math background: I have taken analysis (single and multivariable), linear algebra, analytic geometry, graph theory and discrete mathematics, computability, axiomatic set theory. Currently I am taking a course on a mathematical introduction to logic. I am also currently a TA on Computability (we mainly cover regular languages, and context free languages, and a little bit of turnig machines in the last two weeks). I have also spoken with one of the professors here, and we have arranged weekly meetings to discuss some current research in modal logic (where I hope, I will be able to make some contribution (with the aid of my professor ofcourse) over the remaining two years of my study).

Is it realistically possible to get into a good mathematics graduate school (maybe not Ivy League, but still one that is ranked high in terms of opportunities) and will I be too far behind people who have finished BSc in maths?

Is it a better strategy to switch to a math major(possibly postponing my graduation with at least a year or two)? I'm not trying to dishonor Computer Scientists - its a super cool field, its just that the quality of my courses is low (compared to the math courses), and I'm gonna need the most math I can study if I am to become a successful researcher.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly someone with a major in CS can be admitted to graduate school in mathematics.

You will need to learn to write proofs. (If that is what you have been doing in the math courses you mention: great!)  You will need courses called perhaps "real analysis" and "abstract algebra".

If, after those courses, you still think you want to do mathematics, then go for it.

Comment: I am interested in foundations of mathematics like set theory, model theory, mathematical logic - I will also be taking courses on computability and proof theory. I have experience of writing rigorous proofs, of course, and have taken real analysis and abstract algebra. Do you know whether specializing in the field of foundations of mathematics will enable me to later pursue (if I needed) maybe a specialization in some more applied part of mathematics?